# Recording results from ForEach in PHP

Tags: php

I am attempting to make a basic port scan for penntesting, and am wanting the data to be stored in their own array, rather than each individual port being its own array.

This is my code (I see the issue, but am looking for ways to solve it)

```
$host = $_GET["host"];
$ports = array(80, 443);

foreach ($ports as $port)
{
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);

    if (is_resource($connection)) {
        $out=array("success:true");
        $out2=array("ports:$port");
        echo json_encode($out);
        echo "\n";
        echo json_encode($out2);
    }else{
        $out=array("success:false");
        echo json_encode($out);
    }
        fclose($connection);

}
```

The issue (I think) is the echo command is contained within the ForEach string, and therefore is being ran on its own per port. I am confused how else I could do it. The result I currently get is:

```
["success:true"] ["ports:80"]["success:true"] ["ports:443"]
```

And the result I would like to get is

```
["success:true"] ["ports:80, 443"]
```

Any tips on what I could do differently, or how I could reword this question would be much appreciated!

Edit: Would actually prefer to get an output like this:

```
{"success": true, "ports": 80, 443}
```

If anyone knows how I could achieve this, I would be very thankful for your help!

Edit 2: Also, if a failure were to occur (No ports replied) I would like it to not list the ports which failed, but rather just output something like

```
{"success": false}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your output structure is a little bit confusing, are you sure you would not be happier with a JSON object structure like `{"success": true, "ports": [80, 443]}` which would be more easily machine-readable? Also, did you want to list the ports which failed under `success:false`?

Comment: Solving what you actually asked for isn't difficult either and can be done with a temporary array to accumulate successful ports

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Actually the JSON object structure would be better. How would I go about getting this? I am new to PHP, so I am trying to learn as I go lol. Edit: Add on - And no, I do not want to list the ports which failed. I only want to report that none replied if it is a failure.

Comment: So if _no_ ports reply, that is the only situation where you would like `success: false`? I just want to make sure I understand your requirement because your original loop would have output failures per port too

Comment: Why no collect all data first instead of printing stuff in the middle of the scanning process?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes, I realize I had made that mistake. I do not want the per port failures printed, just telling me there was no ports open.

Comment: @NicoHaase  thats the idea I am trying to figure out how to achieve, to store the open ports until the end then print them all at once in a proper array another machine could read easily.

Comment: So, what have you tried to make this work? Gathering data in an array is not that hard and pretty well documented

Comment: I have tried google searching the question, and found things similar to what I am after, but I have not understood how to make the examples work in my setup. I haven't tried anything else as I do not know how to save the data for being put in their own array, and I likely was searching the wrong keywords to get examples that would work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a JSON structure which allows you to see the success or failure of the connection together with an array of successful ports will be a more machine readable. The loop should gather all the information you need, then after the loop assemble it into a structured array and output it as JSON. I would recommend striving to send output as infrequently as possible - instead of many `echo` in a loop, build an array or string then `echo` once at the end for output.

```
// Start with an empty array to collect successful ports
$ports_success = array();
foreach ($ports as $port)
{
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
    // On success
    if (is_resource($connection)) {
      // Add the port to the array of successes
      $ports_success[] = $port;
    }
}

// Now outside your loop, test if count() of succeeded ports
// is more than zero, meaning you had some succeed
if (count($ports_success) > 0) {
  $success = true;
}
else { 
  $success = false;
}

// Combine your success flag and ports list into json
$output = array(
  'success' => $success,
  'ports' => $ports_success
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

The above would include an empty `ports: []` even on failure. You can exclude that with different logic after the loop.

```
// Start with empty output
$output = array();

if (count($ports_success) > 0) {
  // Only put in the ports if there are some
  $output = array(
    'success' => true,
    'ports' => $ports_success
  );
}
else {
  $output = array(
    'success' => false
  );
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

A final note since you are new to PHP - some of the `if/else` logic can be more succinct if you rely on a boolean evaluation from `count() > 0`. This is how I would probably express it after your loop.

```
$output = array(
  // true if > 0, false otherwise
  'success' => (count($ports_success) > 0),
  'ports' => $ports_success
);
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: I would have solved it very similar the only difference is I would have taken longer

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I extremely appreciate the level of detail you added to this. I also hope to put the boolean evaluation into more use to reduce the number of if statements I use. Thank you again!

Comment: @CorryKnellberg You're welcome, good luck. Any place you find yourself storing true or false into a variable, you can usually substitute a comparison evaluation like `("a" == "b")`. Or if you are setting a variable value based on a condition, you can use `$var = $a == $b ? "value if true" : "value if false";`